# Angular emoji-mart takes too long to load

Tags: angular

I have installed `@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart` in my Angular 7 App.
But when I try to use the emoji mart in html page, it takes too long for the html page to load.

I am using the code :

```
<emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" set="emojione"></emoji-mart>
```

Answer (score 1):

Test in native mode.

```
<emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" set="emojione" isNative="true"></emoji-mart>
```

Comment: Explain what will do the *native-mode*. So the questioner can understand your answer better than just a code-snipped.

Comment: nativ is faster, but this mod is still very slow. Build own div with smiles.

Comment: _nativeMode Renders the native unicode emoji by true/false_ . 

If still having this issues you can update to latest or follow this discussion: [link](https://github.com/jm-david/emoji-mart-vue/issues/9)